# Unit testing with timeouts

Tags: unit-testing, timeout

I am unit testing a class with a property whose value changes often, depending on communication it receives from another component. If the class does not receive any communication for 5 seconds, the property reverts to a default value.

It is easy for me to stub and mock out the communicating component in order to trigger the values I want to test for. The problem is that if I run my unit tests on a machine which is busy (like a build machine), and there is a significant-enough delay to cause the property to default, then my unit test will fail.

**How would you test to be sure that this property has the proper value when simulating various communication conditions?**

One idea is to restructure my code so that I can stub the part of the class which controls the timeout. Another is to write my unit test such that it can detect if it failed due to a timeout and indicates that in the test results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make the timeout property configurable, then set it to a high enough value in your unit tests (or low enough, if you want to unit test the reset behaviour).

Comment: I chose to go this route because it was the simplest solution for my situation. The other suggestions were great as well. Thanks all!

Answer (score 11):

I'd try a different approach. Game developers often need a way to control the game time, e.g. for fast-forward functionality or to synchronize frame rates. They introduce a `Timer` object, which reads ticks from either a hardware clock, or from a simulated clock.

In your case, you could provide a controllable timer for your unit tests and a timer which delegates to system time in production mode. That way, you can control the time which passes for your test case and thus how the class-under-test has to react under certain timeout conditions.

Pseudo-code:

```
public void testTimeout() throws Exception {
  MockTimerClock clock = new MockTimerClock();

  ClassUnderTest cut = new ClassUnderTest();
  cut.setTimerClock(clock);
  cut.beginWaitingForCommunication();

  assertTrue(cut.hasDefaultValues());
  cut.receiveOtherValues();
  assertFalse(cut.hasDefaultValues());

  clock.tick(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  assertTrue(cut.hasDefaultValues());
  cut.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a similar problem when using `DateTime.Now`.
[Ayende described a trick](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/07/07/Dealing-with-time-in-tests.aspx) to deal with it that I liked:

```
public static class SystemTime
{
    public static Func<DateTime> Now = () => DateTime.Now;
}
```

and then in your test :

```
[Test]
public void Should_calculate_length_of_stay_from_today_when_still_occupied()
{
    var startDate = new DateTime(2008, 10, 1);
    SystemTime.Now = () => new DateTime(2008, 10, 5);

    var occupation = new Occupation { StartDate = startDate };

    occupation.LengthOfStay().ShouldEqual(4);
}
```

Maybe you can use the same kind of trick for your timeout?